How to write the transformed result from XsltTransformer to a string which can then be pushed to azure service bus?
I have a requirement of transforming the given xml to json using XsltTransformer which compiles the xslt and then transforms the xml. I want the destination of the XsltTransformer to be either string or azure service bus queue.
Tried creating the BlobOutputStream and passed it to  XsltTransformer destination, still can not see the output in the blob in azure.
        Serializer out = processor.newSerializer();
        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "text");
        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
        .endpoint("blob endpoint") //https://xslttesting.blob.core.windows.net/sample
        .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
        .buildClient();
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient =     blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("sample");
        BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("sample.txt");
        // blobContainerClient.createIfNotExistsWithResponse();
        BlobOutputStream blobOS = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient().getBlobOutputStream();
        out.setOutputStream(blobOS);



        XsltTransformer transformer = executable.load();
        transformer.setInitialContextNode(source);
        transformer.setDestination(out);
        transformer.transform();


Do you have a blobOS.close() after the transform() call? If not, try adding that. Otherwise perhaps give us some more information as to which Java, Saxon version you use.

Does everything work if you substitute a different kind of output stream, for example a ByteArrayOutputStream? If it does, then the problem must be on the Azure side (which means I don't know the answer...). Doing an explicit close() on the stream can't do any harm.

@preeti mallad check the below answer


Tried creating the BlobOutputStream and passed it to XsltTransformer destination, still can not see the output in the blob in azure.

You can use the below code to handles XML to XSLT transformation using Saxon, and writes the transformed output to Azure Blob Storage using Azure's SDK.
Code:
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Processor processor = new Processor(false);
        XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
        XsltExecutable executable = compiler.compile(new StreamSource("C:\\sample.xsl"));
        Source source = new StreamSource("C:\\sample.xml");
        writeToBlobStorage(processor, executable, source);
    }
    public static void writeToBlobStorage(Processor processor, XsltExecutable executable, Source source) throws Exception {
        Serializer out = processor.newSerializer();
        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "text");
        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");        // Set up Blob storage client

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
        .endpoint("blob endpoint") //https://xslttesting.blob.core.windows.net/sample
        .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
        .buildClient();

        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("test");
        BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("sample.txt");

        BlobOutputStream blobOS = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient().getBlobOutputStream();
        out.setOutputStream(blobOS);
        XsltTransformer transformer = executable.load();
        transformer.setInitialContextNode(processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(source));
        transformer.setDestination(out); 
        transformer.transform();
        blobOS.flush();
        blobOS.close();

        System.out.println("Transformation written to Azure Blob Storage successfully.");
    }
}

In the above code the BlobOutputStream is properly flushed and closed to ensure all the data is written to the blob. You can do this by explicitly calling blobOS.flush() and blobOS.close().
Output:
Transformation written to Azure Blob Storage successfully.

Portal:


Is the flush() necessary? I suspect that Saxon is doing a close() on the stream but not a flush(). I've always assumed that a stream would be flushed automatically if you did a close(), but I see that the Javadoc doesn't say that explicitly. Should Saxon be doing a flush() before the close()?

Correction. Saxon follows the rule that whoever creates an OutputStream is responsible for closing it. So Saxon won't close a stream that was created by the user.

Good to hear from you:) @MichaelKay

Or you can call Serializer.setCloseOnCompletion(true).
